# Reading unknown number of objects from file

Tags: java, object, serialization

The assignment is to

> Create a program that accepts and stores data from any Winter
>   Olympics.
>   The program should accept and store up to 6 competitor names for each event
>   as well as the name of the event they participated in. It should also sort
>   the scores or times of the events showing the medal winners only with
>   the medal they won.

I have created an "Event" class which is going smoothly, but I run into problems when trying to write the "Event" objects to a file and read them.

Here is my method to create a new event:

```
public static void addEvent() {
    File events = new File("events.dat");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String eventName;
    ArrayList<Event> olympics = new ArrayList<Event>();
    boolean fileExists = false;

    if (events.exists()) {
        fileExists = true;
    } else {
        try {
            events.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("File created");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File could not be created");
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Enter name of event: ");
    eventName = input.nextLine();
    olympics.add(new Event(eventName));

    //write Objects
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(events, fileExists);
        ObjectOutputStream writeEvent = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        writeEvent.writeObject(olympics);
        writeEvent.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File could not be found.");
        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem with input/output.");
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    menu();
}// end addEvent()
```

And my method to display the file:

```
public static void displayFile(File datFile) {
    File events = datFile;
    String output ="";

    //read objects
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(events);
        ObjectInputStream readEvents = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        ArrayList<Event> recoveredEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

        while (readEvents.readObject() != null) {
            recoveredEvents.add((Event)readEvents.readObject());
        }
        readEvents.close();
        for (Event e: recoveredEvents) {
            //System.out.println(e + "\n");
            output += e + "\n";
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist or could not be found");
        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file");
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class could not be used to cast object.");
        System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    menu();
}// end displayFile()
```

This is a beginning class and handling files has been difficult to wrap my head around so far. Edit: Forgot to mention that it throws an IOException with the message "null" when I try to call displayFile().

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @frenchDolphin sorry, how do I do that? I'm a beginner, remember ;)

Comment: OK sorry. When you get your IOException, what is the specific error message you get? It should look something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors); look at the top of the post.

Comment: A post on that page also explains what a stack trace is: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/3761440)

Comment: I forgot something, see [here](http://pastebin.com/UwK0FPRL). You won't see any stack trace without it!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was getting an EOFException, which @EJP mentioned.

Comment: Also, who is downvoting my question and why?

Answer (score 2):

1. You're getting `EOFException`. When `readObject()` gets to the end of the stream it doesn't return null. Check the Javadoc. It throws `EOFException.` You should catch this separately and not treat it as an error that needs reporting.
2. You're throwing away every odd element. Your read loop should look like:

   ```
   while (true)
   {
       recoveredEvents.add((Event)readObject.readObject());
   }
   ```
3. You can't append to a file written by `ObjectOutputStream`. You will get `IOException: invalid type code AC` when you get to the join when reading. There are ways around this but they are non-trivial. Keep the file open.
4. `new FileOutputStream()` creates the file. All that exists/createNewFile crud before it is just a waste of time and space.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Now my only question is about your 3rd point. What do you mean by "keep the file open"? If I open the file with my addEvent() method, will the file still be open for me to use with my displayFile() method?

Comment: Not calling `close` keeps the file open.